# Where do I read about semi-algebraic/analytic sets?

Tags: reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry, real-analytic-structures, semialgebraic-geometry

What's a good introduction to semi-algebraic/semi-analytic sets?

I'm coming from algebraic geometry, so ideally I'd prefer material that has a similar point of view and highlights analogies.

I've seen the wikipedia pages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subanalytic_set and the references there.
I thought I'd ask here, before plunging into them.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Real-Geometry-Societies-Transition/dp/3110150956/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1449524654&sr=8-4&keywords=broglia+real

Comment: certainly, Bochnak, Jacek; Coste, Michel; Roy, Marie-Françoise. Real Algebraic Geometry. Translated from the 1987 French original. Revised by the authors. Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete (3) [Results in Mathematics and Related Areas (3)], 36. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1998. x+430 pp

Comment: and this: https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf

Comment: Thanks (to both)! If you'd like to write your suggestions as an answer, I'll accept it if nobody writes anything more detailed...

Comment: You can also look at Claus Scheiderer's survey ["Positivity and sums of squares: A guide to recent results"](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~scheider/preprints/GUIDE.pdf)